# Retrieving an image from a SQL Server database in vb.net using a http handler

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm currently battling to retrieve an image from SQL Server 2008 R2 in an asp web application using vb.net. The image is stored in the SQL Server 2008 R2 database as an image type. I've been researching for the past few days and can't seem to find anything solid on this topic. Apparently, the image has to be retrieved using a http handler, and then then image control's imageurl property needs to reference that?

What kind of item needs to be added to the project for this .ashx page?

Please can someone post me some code for both the http handler and the aspx page using vb.net.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tip #1: drop the `IMAGE` type - it's been deprecated since SQL Server 2005. Use `VARBINARY(MAX)` instead

Answer (score 1):

You don't **have to** use a HTTP handler - there are other ways to do this. But using an HTTP handler is an elegant and quite nice way to achieve this.

Read these resources - they should you step-by-step how to achieve this:

- [Serving Dynamic Content with HTTP Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx)
- [Displaying images in ASP.NET using HTTP handlers](http://www.worldofasp.net/tut/images/Displaying_images_in_ASPNET_using_HttpHandlers_92.aspx)

Comment: Cool links! I would add that you don't need to register the handlers if you're using ASPNET 4.0. Also, set the IsReusable property to true if you're presenting multiple images, say in a grid :)

Comment: Thanks for the links. If it's not necessary though, what would you recommend is the easiest way? I just want to get it working and move on. It's been bothering me for quite a while

Comment: This site will never go live, so it's just for demonstration purposes

Comment: @Matt: basically, you could also do something like the second link shows - a direct `Response.BinaryWrite` into your response stream. That would render your images, too. Depends on how you need to display those images...